# Get nested data from Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nested

Here is how I get the data:

[image]

Currently when I `console.log(snapshotData.data);` I get an array of this:

[image]

what I want to get is editorState, blocks, 0, text. I tried to get it using `snapshotData.data.editorState.blocks.[0].text`, and `snapshotData.data.editorState.blocks.0.text` and it didn't work

again, I want to get this:

[image]

On Firestore it's says: editorState is map, blocks -> array, 0 -> map, text -> string

[image]

Comment: the text its too long here is the photo, URL: https://imgur.com/a/Pp3ZfUl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by using optional chaining

```
  console.log(snapshotData?.data?.editorState?.blocks[0]?.text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
// if blocks is an Array
snapshotData.data.editorState.blocks[0].text
```

or

```js
// if '0' is a key corresponding to the smaller object
snapshotData.data.editorState.blocks["0"].text
```

#### Update

According to the screenshot uploaded, `blocks` is actually an array containing one single object.

You should use the first code block I provided, i.e.

```js
snapshotData.data.editorState.blocks[0].text
```

Comment: yes, blocks is an array, I tried using the first code example but it didn't work, I get this err: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'editorState')

Comment: Are you sure that `snapshotData.data` corresponds to the data you see on Firebase firestore?

Comment: For my projects, my access for firestore data is like:

Comment: `const DataRef = admin.firestore().collection( <collection name> );`

Comment: `DataRef.get().then( item => item.docs[0].data() )`

Comment: To get the actual data you want to do snapshoot.docs[0]?.data().editorState?.blocks[0]?.text

Comment: Snapshot.data() will get you data. Not snapshot.data

Comment: @newdeveloper here is how I get the data, link: https://imgur.com/a/93vHtcH

Comment: @on9_jai im getting the data, i can get the fileName using snapshotData.data.fileName, but when  i try to access editorState, blocks, 0, text I get error

Comment: ok, I fixed it, I just needed to use optional chaining, here is how I fixed:   console.log(snapshotData?.data?.editorState?.blocks[0]?.text);